# StackTraceElement for tracking an exception

Tags: java, exception

This one is a little bit tough to explain, so sorry for the long question!

I have the method indexOf(String node) which looks in a string-array and returns the index-position or throws an Exception if it can't find node-string in the array.

This method is used in addEdge(String node1, String node2) to call addEdge(int index1, int index2).

```
protected String[] nodes;
protected boolean[][] adjacencyMatrix;

protected int indexOf(String node) throws GraphException {
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        if (node.equals(nodes[i])) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Exception in indexOf(String node)");
    throw new GraphException();
}

public void addEdge(int index1, int index2) throws GraphException {
    if ((index1 != index2) && (index1 < this.nodes.length) && (index2 < this.nodes.length)) {
        this.adjacencyMatrix[index1][index2] = true;
        this.adjacencyMatrix[index2][index1] = true;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Exception in addEdge(int index1, int index2)");
        throw new GraphException();
    }
}

public void addEdge(String node1, String node2) throws GraphException {
    try {
        this.addEdge(this.indexOf(node1), this.indexOf(node2));

    } catch (GraphException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception in addEdge(String node1, String node2)");
        throw new GraphException();
    }
}
```

For testing purposes, I have implemented an array with myArray = {"foo", "foo2", "bar"}. Now, when I try something to provoke the exception, like:

```
try {
        addEdge("foo", "foobar");

    } catch (GraphException e) {
        for (StackTraceElement st : e.getStackTrace()) {
            System.out.println("Method: " + st.getMethodName() + " Line: " + st.getLineNumber());
        }
    }
```

the console-output is:

```
Exception in indexOf(String node)
Exception in addEdge(String node1, String node2)
Method: addEdge Line: 169
Method: main Line: 221
```

**Ok, here's the question:**

Apperently, the exception must have been thrown in indexOf(String node) the first time, since there is no matching "foobar" string in the nodes-array.

That's explaining the first .println: **Exception in indexOf(String node)**.

So, is there a reason the Stack is missing out this first position where the Exception gets thrown?

I would have expected something like this from the stack:

```
Method: indexOf Line: 58
Method: addEdge Line: 169
Method: main Line: 221
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exception is being caught in `addEdge(string, string)` and rethrown, so that's where the stacktrace starts.

If you want to preserve the actual initiating stacktrace, you'll have to modify `GraphException` so that it can also carries the previous exception:

```
throw new GraphException (e);
```

Comment: Or you can simply rethrow the prior exception.  Or transfer the stack trace from the prior exception to the new one.